# Drools on Weblogic Server

Tags: drools, weblogic12c

I tried to evaluate JBoss BRMS on weblogic server but I was told by the red hat support that JBoss BRMS doesn't Weblogic directly and they don't have any document towards the installation and they cannot help on this.

So now I am trying to evaluate Drools on Weblogic. My question: Is Drools 6.0 supported on weblogic 12c?

Answer (score 0):

Drools 6 works on any JVM 1.6+, so it should work on Weblogic too. There's nothing in the code (and never will be) that purposely prevents that.

However, because app servers usually have a big classpath already, figuring out which jars shouldn't be included in a war's WEB-INF/lib folder can prove painstaking - and to make things worse - there is no elaborate QA vs Weblogic. So it's probably much easier to use JBoss instead (which is thoroughly supported by Red Hat support).